# Até quantos níveis diferentes um classificador pode predizer?

Tags: python, algoritmo, data, machine-learning, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Recentemente estava fazendo um modelo de aprendizagem de máquina e fiquei na dúvida se deveria usar regressão logística. A documentação diz que esse classificador pode predizer em valores binários (0 ou 1). No meu caso, eu tinha 4 valores possíveis e fiquei na dúvida se poderia usar ou não ele. Por isso, acabei optando pelo random forest.

Entretanto, fiquei com uma dúvida. Se eu tivesse usado algum outro algoritmo de classificação, até quantos valores ele pode prever? No gráfico de exemplo do SVM, no site do scikit-learn , ele mostra até 3 possíveis valores distintos.

Answer (score 3):

A não ser que seja um classificador binário, não há limite para o número de classes que um classificador possa trabalhar. Regressão logística é um classificador binário, portanto não pode ser utilizado para realizar uma tarefa de classificação cuja variável resposta possua 3 ou mais níveis.

Assim como Random Forest, o SVM também é multiclasse e, portanto, pode ser utilizado no problema em questão.